# How to remove nested Many to Many association when Parent object get delete - Hibernate JPA 2

Tags: hibernate, jpa, hibernate-mapping, jpa-2.1

Below is my mapping relations.

```
public class User {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    @Column(name = "USER_ID")
    private Long userId;



    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER,cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinTable(name = "USERGROUP_MEMBERS", joinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "USER_ID")}, inverseJoinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "GROUP_ID")})
    private List<UserGroup> userGroups;

    // Getter & Setters

}
```

```
public class UserGroup  {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "GROUP_ID")
    private Long groupId;

    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER,cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinTable(name="GROUP_AUTHORITIES",joinColumns={@JoinColumn(name="GROUP_ID")}, inverseJoinColumns={@JoinColumn(name="AUTHORITY_ID")})
    private List<Authority> groupAuthorities;

    // Getter & Setters 

}
```

```
public class Authority {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "AUTHORITY_ID")
    private Long authorityId;
    @Column(name = "AUTHORITY_NAME")
    private String authorityName;

   // Getter & Setters 
}
```

When I delete `User` Object i want to delete only associated `usergroups` but it's  deleting the nested relation of `UserGroup.groupAuthorities` when there is match bound with `GROUP_ID` .

I want to avoid this `groupAuthorities` deletion when User get removed is it possible is there a way to do that?

```
public void deleteUser(Long id) {

    User user = (User) getEntityManager().find(User.class, id);
    getEntityManager().remove(user);
    flush();

}
```